# Unit Testing with ASP.NET webservice?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, unit-testing, namespaces

I am trying to unit test some of the methods I have written in an ASP.NET web service. To the project I have added a new Unit Test Project but the problem is I can't access the classes and methods from the unit test class. How can I fix this issue ?

Comment: well, what have you tried? What do you mean you cannot access the classes? did you add a reference to the projects? are you mocking the classes or interfaces? What are you doing?

Comment: At the moment, just simply writing testing the method calls with [TestMethod]. I tried adding the reference of my code namespace to the Unit Test project but it didn't work...

Comment: what didn't work? you do know you need to write code to test the methods, right? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182532.aspx https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh694602.aspx https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182524(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a reference to the web service project. Once you do this, you should be able to start adding tests.

NOTE: The actual functionality is refactored to classes outside of the "web service" classes, if you want to test. Even better, move the core functionality to its own class library and run the unit tests there. As a best practice, you should also make interfaces for all classes so you can employ some type of dependency injection (either feed the classes or use an IoC container, or similar)